# map an array into objects with a specific field as the reference

Tags: json, group-by, jq

I have the following JSON array constructed out of ZFS pool information to which a node field as been added (which could have many elements of course as there are many nodes):

```
[
  {
    "NodeName": "node1",
    "VolumeName": "vol1",
    "Size": "50.0T",
    "Used": "18.6T",
    "Free": "31.4T",
    "Fragmentation": "31%",
    "Capacity": "37%",
    "Health": "ONLINE"
  },
  {
    "NodeName": "node1",
    "VolumeName": "vol2",
    "Size": "796G",
    "Used": "28.5M",
    "Free": "796G",
    "Fragmentation": "0%",
    "Capacity": "0%",
    "Health": "ONLINE"
  }
]
```

And I would like to map this into this type of object format, promoting a field to be the new 'key' and return an object with that field as the key to an array of the original data without that key: (Almost like grouping the data by a particular field)

```
{
  "node1": [
    {
      "VolumeName": "vol1",
      "Size": "50.0T",
      "Used": "18.6T",
      "Free": "31.4T",
      "Fragmentation": "31%",
      "Capacity": "37%",
      "Health": "ONLINE"
    },
    {
      "VolumeName": "vol2",
      "Size": "796G",
      "Used": "28.5M",
      "Free": "796G",
      "Fragmentation": "0%",
      "Capacity": "0%",
      "Health": "ONLINE"
    }
  ]
}
```

I believe map or group-by are the way to go but not getting the required result. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank.

Comment: Can you post the efforts you made into the question?

Answer (score 1):

Group by `.NodeName`, and index each group with that value in an object. Then remove `NodeName` field from all members.

```
group_by(.NodeName)
| INDEX(.[]; .[0].NodeName)
| del(.[][].NodeName)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JRNOgF8AJb)</sup>